# Disable Linux Mint Alt-F1 shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint and experimenting with IntelliJ.

IntelliJ has a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut (Select in...). Unfortunately it is also used by Mint to display an overview of workspaces.

I would like to keep the shortcut's use for IntelliJ and disable it in Mint.

Where can I disable this <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in Mint? I can't see it anywhere in Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question over at super user instead of Stack Overflow.
http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I actually found the answer at superuser.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As CharliePrynn pointed out, [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) would be a better place for this question.

I actually found the solution there: https://superuser.com/questions/531874/disable-alt-f1-keyboard-shortcut-in-cinnamon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]"
```

plus logout & login

Answer (score 0):

You can install "CompizConfig Settings Manager" and disable shortcut in "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"  section.

[CompizConfig Download](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/compizconfig-settings-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts..., and uncheck "Enable menu access keys".

*Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana
base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal*

Comment: Pleas specify the version of Linux Mint that you are using since thus was asked a long time ago